# How to add extra value to select query result

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

SubjectMaster

```
Id  Subject
1   English
2   History
3   Maths
```

UserSubjectAssociation

```
Id Userid SubjectId
1   1     1
2   1     3
3   2     2
```

Logs

```
Id  Userid  SubjectId Examdate     Percentage 
1   1       1          02/20/2020  50
2   1       0          Null        Null
3   2       1           02/20/2020  70
4   2       2           02/20/2020  60
5   3       0            Null        Null
6   4       3           02/18/2020  56
```

These are my sample tables.

I want to show records from log table of zero as well as  all assigned subject of user 1

Suppose user 1 has 2 subject 1 and 3.
Show records from logs where subjectid comes in 0 as well as 1,3

Required Output :

Logs

```
Id  Userid  SubjectId Examdate     Percentage 
1   1       1          02/20/2020  50
2   1       0          Null        Null
3   2       1           02/20/2020  70
4   3       0            Null        Null
5  4       3           02/18/2020  56
```

Query :

select * from logs where rdatetime >= '' and subjectid in (select id from subjectmaster where userid = 1)

'Or' did not work.It was giving wrong output.How to handle it.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am using sql server 2013 .I have already shown required output

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a correlated subquery and condition like this:

```
select l.*
from logs l 
where l.subjectid = 0 or
      exists (select 1
              from subjectmaster sm
              where sm.userid = l.userid and
                    sm.subjectid = l.subjectid
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do `left join` :

```
select l.*
from logs l left join
     subjectmaster sm
     on sm.userid = l.userid and
        sm.subjectid = l.subjectid
where not (l.subjectid <> 0 and sm.subjectid is null);
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the desired result:

```
select * 
from logs l
where subjectid = 0 
      OR
      subjectid IN (select subjectid 
                    from UserSubjectAssociation 
                    where Userid = 1)
```